# Does any body know to align script tag in html? As I have to align the script tags one below the other

Tags: html, whitespace, indentation, code-formatting

I am developing a website for a mobile using jquery. where i haave to use charts like Bar, pie, line etc. as this is been achhieved through Javascript. i have imported all the charts which i needed. but i have to align these charts one by one in a vertical line. so please help me to attain this. and following is my code. i have also fiddled it but i didnt get the complete output. http://jsfiddle.net/2VPUX/1/

```
<!doctype html> 

<script src="http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/vendor/d3.v2.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/rickshaw.min.js"></script> 
Bar Graph 
<div id="chart"></div> 
<script> 
    var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
    element: document.querySelector("#chart"),
    width: 400,
    height: 850,
    renderer: 'bar',
    series: [ {
    data: [ { x: 0, y: 40 }, { x: 1, y: 49 }, { x: 2, y: 38 }, { x: 3, y: 30 },   { x: 4, y: 32 } ],
        color: 'Black'
    } ]
    } );
    graph.render();
    </script> 

    <div id="chart" align="left"></div>
    <script> 
      var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph({
      element: document.querySelector("#chart"),
      width: 400,
      height: 850,
      renderer: 'line',
      series: [{
      data: [ { x: 0, y: 40 }, { x: 1, y: 49 }, { x: 2, y: 38 }, { x: 3, y: 30 },  { x: 4, y: 32 } ],
          color: 'Red'
      }, {
      data: [ { x: 0, y: 20 }, { x: 1, y: 24 }, { x: 2, y: 37 }, { x: 3, y: 15 },  { x: 4, y: 16 } ],
      color: 'Black'
}]
  });
     graph.render();
    </script> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Vehicle Sales', 'Per Year'],
      ['Cars',     15],
      ['Bus',      12],
      ['Lorry',  10],
      ['Two Wheeler', 45],
      ['Others',    18]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Pie Chart'
    };

    var chart = new  google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
   </script>
  </head>
 <body>
   <div id="chart_div" align="left" style="width: 900px; height: 600px; float: left">     </div>
  </body>
   <div id="chart" align="left"></div> 
   <script> 
      var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
element: document.querySelector("#chart"),
width: 435,
height: 200,
renderer: 'area',
stroke: true,
series: [ {
    data: [ { x: 0, y: 40 }, { x: 1, y: 49 }, { x: 2, y: 38 }, { x: 3, y: 30 }, { x: 4, y: 32 } ],
    color: 'Maroon'
} ]
  } );
     graph.render();

    </script> 
      <div id="chart"></div> 
     <script> 
      var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
element: document.querySelector("#chart"),
width: 1000,
height: 85,
renderer: 'scatterplot',
stroke: true,
padding: { top: 0.05, left: 0.05, right: 0.05 },
series: [ {
    data: [ { x: 0, y: 40 }, { x: 1, y: 49 }, { x: 2, y: 38 }, { x: 3, y: 30 }, { x: 4, y: 32 }, { x: 5, y: 40 }, { x: 6, y: 49 }, { x: 7, y: 38 }, { x: 8, y: 30 }, { x: 9, y: 32}  ],
    color: 'Black'
} ]
 } );
   graph.render();

   </script>
```

Comment: What is that library? It shouldn't work like I think it does.

Comment: The script tags themselves are not visible, but the elements produced by them arey. Style those, or their wrappers.

Comment: http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/ is the link from where i have used the charts.

Comment: You have duplicate IDs. That's bad.

Comment: You have duplicate IDs. All your charts are overwriting each other, into the first `div` with that ID (my fears it uses `document.write` didn't fulfill).

Comment: Fix the IDs first, then we talk.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to align these charts one by one in a vertical line

```css
#container { display: block; }
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect x="25" y="15" height="15" width="15" style="fill:red;"/>
<rect x="25" y="45" height="15" width="15" style="fill:black;"/>
<rect x="25" y="75" height="15" width="15" style="fill:green;"/>
</svg>
```